# What to use instead of "goto"-method in my code?

Tags: c#

```cs
menu2:
    WriteLine("New category");
    WriteLine("***************************");
    WriteLine();

    Write("Name: ");

    string categoryName = ReadLine();

    WriteLine("Is this correct? (Y)es (N)o");

    Category category = new Category(categoryName);

    do
    {
        userInput = ReadKey(true);

        invalidSelection = !(userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Y ||
            userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.N);
    }
    while (invalidSelection);

    var categoryExist = categoryList.Any(x => x.CategoryName == categoryName);

    switch (userInput.Key)
    {

        case ConsoleKey.Y:
            {
                if (!categoryExist)
                {
                    categoryList.Add(category);
                    Clear();
                    WriteLine("Category created!");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Clear();
                    WriteLine("Category already exist");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Clear();
                }
                break;
            }


        case ConsoleKey.N:

            Clear();

            goto menu2;
    }
    break;
```

I'm kinda new to programming and I've realized that people reaaalllyy don't like "goto"-methods. What else can i use? For example, in the code, the user inputs a category, and is then asked wether he/she typed in the category name correctly if YES then we add it if NO then u jump back to Name and have to type it in one more time. How could I do this without having to use go-to method?

Comment: You can use a loop.

Comment: `goto` is good enough for the compiler: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp2YlZEA8AlgHYAuAfOgGIB7AQAombLr1acApgFsAzgEpa9Gknob0AMwEAnaQEMAxgAt0wgG4Hd6KXNvtbMhcvWa6a9+9Zbzd2egAvIHoMK5eEZhwcJgA7Ohw+G6Rtr7C/kEhcOEpmlgxUPEwSREAvip05UilQA== - https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Er9.png | so why not for you?

Comment: Nothing wrong with goto unless you are experiencing an _actual_ problem from using it.

Comment: @RandRandom IL doesn't have loops. Blame your decompiler, not the C# compiler :)

Comment: @Luaan - didn't know that, always thought that the compiler does some optimization and this bearly readable code is generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already use the same thing in your code - a do-while loop will do nicely.

It also helps to separate your code into logical blocks "hidden" in methods. That can help the readability of code like this, where you have distinct menus - instead of having a long block of code with multiple gotos, you can keep each level of the menu as its own method, and each call can be surrounded by a loop (or the method itself, depending on your preference).

Methods also give you the option to use `return`, which in many similar cases serves as a good replacement for `goto`-using code.

As you get deeper into understanding C#, new options for simplification and/or abstraction open up. For example, you can replace multiple occurrences of the same (logical) loop with functions or classes/interfaces. No rush, though :)